# mvvm light коммерческое использование

Tags: mvvm-light

скажите пожалуйста, можно ли использовать библиотеки в коммерческих целях? если да, то какие требования распространяются?

Comment: Обратитесь к авторам библиотеки. Точный ответ знают только они.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVVM Light распространяется под лицензией MIT. Это значит, что использование библиотеки в коммерческих продуктах разрешено без каких-либо ограничений. Единственное условие -- вы должны включить [оригинальный копирайт и текст оригинальной лицензии](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/license) в копии своего продукта (видимо, в свою собственную лицензию или readme).

Comment: благодарю за ответ! к сожалению нет кармы плюсануть

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека MVVM Ligth позволяет использовать ее в комерческих продуктах, с условием упоминания о том, что используются технологии разработанные в рамках проекта MVVM Ligth. Ну или если по русски, то да, юзай, только незабудь за нас в титрах. как то так
Если хочется почитать оригинальный текст лицинзионного соглашения, то вот оно https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/license